# Reading file name containing square brackets with Databricks Autoloader

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, databricks-autoloader

I try to read csv files located in Azure Storage Account with Databricks Autoloader. Some of these files contain square brackets in their names. So when trying to read these files with Autoloader by using certain pattern matching with pathGlobfilter, I get the following error:

`org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input Pattern abfss://containername@storageaccountname.dfs.core.windows.net/foldername/File name [file1]_2023.csv matches 0 files`

Reading a single file as

`spark.read.format("csv").options(header='true').load('abfss://containername@storageaccountname.dfs.core.windows.net/foldername/File name [file1]_2023.csv')`

gives the following error: AnalysisException: [PATH_NOT_FOUND] Path does not exist.

However, escaping square brackets when reading a single file with “?” works properly:
`spark.read.format("csv").options(header='true').load('abfss://containername@storageaccountname.dfs.core.windows.net/foldername/File name ?file1?_2023.csv')`

Is it possible to read these files with Autoloader?

Comment: Can you please share the pattern that you gave that did not work ? And the command used to read ?

Comment: I used this command: 

aaa= spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")\
  .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")\
  .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", "abfss:// containername@storageaccountname.dfs.core.windows.net / checkpoints/checkpoint1")\
  .option("cloudFiles.schemaEvolutionMode", "addNewColumns")\
  .option("readerCaseSensitive", "False")\
  .option("pathGlobfilter", "*name*.csv")\
.load("abfss://containername@storageaccountname.dfs.core.windows.net/{folder1,folder2}/")\

display(aaa)

trying to read the filed named  File name [file1]_2023.csv located in folder1.

Comment: If you use only filename.csv, it doesn't give you the results correctly.
You can use pattern like `filename*[file1]*2023.csv` or `filename*file1*2023.csv`  or as given the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Even i got the same error when i tried passing the full filename.

[image]

So, the pattern will be like below.
`*[file1]*2023.csv`

[image]

You can use the same in `pathGlobfilter`.

```
df = spark\
    .readStream\
    .schema(schema)\
    .format("cloudFiles")\
    .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")\
    .option("checkpointLocation", "check_point_location")\
    .option("pathGlobFilter","*[file1]*.csv" )\
    .load("/csvs/")
```

[image]

If you want to read all files of all years.

`*[file1]*.csv`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
This pattern works perfectly. Actually, in reality my directory will contain files which may or may not have square brackets in their names. And those with brackets may contain different strings inside. 
So files in my directory would be named something like this: 
File name [file1]_2023.csv
File name [eee]_2023.csv
File name databricks 2023.csv

What I will need to do is to select these files based on “name”:  option("pathGlobfilter", "* name *.csv")

Is it possible to create a pattern with pathGlobfilter to read all of these files?

Comment: Actually the pattern filename*[file1]*2023.csv  does  not work with autoloader. 
I also tried this one:  filename * \ [ * \ ] *.csv and it seems to correctly identify the files when inferring the schema, however later it gives the same error: 
InvalidInputException: Input Pattern matches 0 files.
Still searching for the approach to escape square brackets with autoloader.

Comment: You need to check filename with [] brackets also or only filename ending with .csv?

Comment: I need to find only files that contain “filename” in their names. But some of the files that match this pattern contain square brackets and because of this autoloader is unable to read any of the files.

Comment: you can try this one `*filename*.csv` right? earlier you told.what you getting for this?